# Message from extension to web page [Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, message

I'm trying to open a web page from an extension and send a message to it. But I get an error on the page where I get the message. Please help, here is my code.

Error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

mainfest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
        "ids": [
            "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc"
        ],
        "matches": [
          "http://localhost:8080/*",
          "http://localhost:8080/",
          "http://localhost:8080/plugin.html"
        ],
        "accepts_tls_channel_id": true
      },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

popup.js(extension):

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://localhost:8080/plugin.html" }, function(tab) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tab.id, "test");
});
```

plugin.html(web page):

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect("abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc");
port.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert(request.message);
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You could get more visibility by making the title of your issue a little more explicit, by putting the error you got in it for example. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: There's no API to send messages to web pages. There's only API to receive messages from web pages as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage): the page sends a message and the extension responds. As a workaround you can use standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent or postMessage.